# Cannot locate symbol 'tcgetattr' referenced by "libcrypto.so"

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, openssl

I'm building a helper library for Android apps and I need a full OpenSSL implementation for some of the support libraries I'm using. I'm creating a build chain and compiling `libssl` and `libcrypto` with it but at runtime I get:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
  Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library:
    soinfo_relocate(linker.cpp:975): cannot locate symbol "tcgetattr" referenced by "libcrypto.so.1.0.0"...
```

I'm guessing there's something I need to do to help locate `tcgetattr` at runtime?

Comment: You probably build using Android platform libraries for API 21 (Android 5.0 Lollipop), but test on a device that runs API 19 (Android 10 KitKat), or lower.

Comment: @AlexCohn You're a life saver! That was it! I'm guessing we need to build on API 19 (testing that now)? Something else?
*Feel free to post an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android runtime has significantly changed between API 19 and API 21. The NDK libraries reflect this change, and many symbols (e.g. **srand**) are now exported from the system libraries. Therefore is important to set **APP_PLATFORM** (if Android.mk is used) or **platformVersion** (if experimental plugin is used) not higher than the lowest SDK version that your app supports.