# Android-NDK: Unsatisfied Link Error : Cannot load library: soinfo_relocate: cannot locate symbol "tcgetattr"

Tags: android-ndk

I am building the app available at https://github.com/thibautd/android-serialport-api/tree/master/android-serialport-api/project using Android NDK.
What have I done until now:

1. Build the project using gradle version 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.0-alpha1'
2. I am building this on android-17 and running on Android device with 4.2. I have also tried android-19
3. Build goes through without any errors but at runtime I get the exception Cannot load library: soinfo_relocate: cannot locate symbol "tcgetattr"

I have tried several options to get this working but all of them fail
Options I have tried

1. Setting APP-PLATFORM like mentioned in [Cannot locate symbol 'tcgetattr' referenced by "libcrypto.so"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33205649/cannot-locate-symbol-tcgetattr-referenced-by-libcrypto-so)
2. Using $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY) by including the .so file avialable in the same github location as mentioned in [How can i Link prebuilt shared Library to Android NDK project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870435/how-can-i-link-prebuilt-shared-library-to-android-ndk-project)
3. Tried setting LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES in both option 1) and 2) above as mentioned in the same post [How can i Link prebuilt shared Library to Android NDK project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870435/how-can-i-link-prebuilt-shared-library-to-android-ndk-project)
4. Also tried option mentioned at [Cannot load library: reloc_library[1285]: cannot locate 'rand'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27338318/cannot-load-library-reloc-library1285-cannot-locate-rand)
5. Put all the required include files directly in the project under /jni and tried building the project.

My project compiles absolutely fine. When testing I have always deleted the contents in build folder and rebuilt the project. To make sure the .so files are indeed created properly.
In all the cases I end up in exactly the same error soinfo_relocate: cannot locate symbol "tcgetattr"

I think it is because of the fact that some of the includes like unistd.h are not correctly referenced in runtime but I am  not able to figure out how to get this working.